# Using .play() .pause() functions from "anime.js" in "react-anime" wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anime.js

I currently have this piece of code to rotate a button SVG 180 degrees when clicked

```
<button onClick={this.xxxx.play()}>
    <Anime autoplay={false} duration={300} rotate="180">
        <img className="arrow-button" src="./Logos/navArrow.svg" alt="" width="50px" height="50px"></img>
    </Anime>
</button>
```

is there a way for me to call the .play() function of the  component with the react-anime wrapper or will i have to include anime.js and do it myself that way?

[link to the react-anime wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-anime)

[link to the anime.js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/animejs)

Comment: Provide exact name of the library you are using with links to it, so we will know for sure what to look.

Comment: @AlexShtromberg i added links to the question